# Ubuntu keeps creating dummy directories

Tags: home-directory, directory

Whenever I boot into Ubuntu, *something* (frankly, I'm not sure which program does that) creates a bunch of directories, namely ***~/Music***, ***~/Videos***, ***~/Documents***, and ***~/Audiobooks***.

I know it's possible to change the names of these directories with ubuntu-tweak, but I don't want these directories in the first place...

How do I prevent Ubuntu, or whatever program is responsible for the creation of these Directories, from creating them?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Go to System → Preferences → Startup Application and disable "User folder update".

[image]

Comment: short and simple- that did the trick. thank you! :D

Comment: Is this still the case in 12.4?  Because I don't have this as a startup application, and yet the annoying directories are still being created.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use UbuntuTweak to set them to arbitrary directories.