# What keeps creating the ~/Snapshots directory?

Tags: home-directory

This question is similar to [Ubuntu keeps creating dummy directories](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16031/ubuntu-keeps-creating-dummy-directories), except it's about the `~/Snapshots` directory. I don't have that startup application, and I've moved all of Ubuntu's directories away from there - the only one I can't find is the Snapshots. It's always empty, and seems quite useless.

The only startup applications I have are Google Chrome and the Gnome Gmail Open Office Configurator.

Comment: Have you used a backup utility, and/or did a backup of your system?

Comment: No, never. And it's the only thing I can find in Google search results...

Comment: Are there any files in the directory?  What are they called?

Comment: @SteveKroon, no, it's completely empty.

Comment: Any luck in getting to the bottom of this? `inotifywait` might help here

Comment: @kolypto: Nope. I stopped using Linux as my main OS after a couple of months though, and that got rid of it :P

Comment: I have found the reason. In my case they were memory snapshots taken by Yourkit profiler.

Comment: In my case it was VirtualBox that was creating a `Snapshots` folder in the home directory. I had to change it in VirtualBox settings.

Comment: As @GáborLipták suggested, the same was the case with me. It was snapshots taken by Yourkit profiler I used few months ago and totally forgot about it.